# Smart door lock with logging of mechanical key opening

Tags: security, home-security, smart-home

I'm searching smart door lock for my small business.

I checked [Xiaomi Aqara Smart Door Lock](https://www.gearbest.com/access-control/pp_1142172.html), [Igloohome](https://www.igloohome.co/), [Samsung lockers](https://www.samsungdigitallife.com/) but all af them CAN NOT log door openings by mechanical key.

Does anyone know smart door lock which CAN log openings by mechanical key ?

Answer (score 1):

The Sesame smart lock from [Candyhouse](https://candyhouse.co/) allows for bluetooth operation, as many of these products provide, but also allows one to open the deadbolt manually. When the lock is operated manually, from within or outside, logging and notification is available.

This may not meet your requirements, as one cannot determine if the action is performed with a key or by an operative within the building.

Our Sesame sends a notification to my phone for manual only but I think it logs the bluetooth activations.